# jQuery Iteration by class selection is slower than id selection

Tags: jquery, performance, selector

I have to iterate a group of `<ul>` having `<li>`s and filter it based on the word typed.  The first code based on id is working good. But the problem is we have duplicate IDs and that is breaking the filter. So, I assigned the IDs for class and did a class selection and now it is working good but having some issues. The main issue is the class selection filter is slower than the Id selection filter. Since it is a big list I can experience slowness when iterating with class names. Is there any way I can make it faster? Also I wonder why the class selection is slower!

Here is my code iterating based on id:

```
  $.each(propertiesList, function () {
    var item = $("#" + this.id).parent();
    if(this.property.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
      item.addClass('no-match');
    }
    else {
      item.parents('.root-property-category').show().addClass('expanded').children('ul').show();
      item.removeClass('no-match');
    }
  });
```

Here is the iteration based on class:

```
$.each(propertiesList, function () {
        var item = $("#available-properties [class*='" + this.id + "']").parent();
        if(this.property.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
            console.log(item)
          item.addClass('no-match');
        }
        else {
            console.log(item)
          item.parents('.root-property-category').show().addClass('expanded').children('ul').show();
          item.removeClass('no-match');
        }
      });
```

Comment: I think class selection will always be slower than ID selection. You might get better results if you try to select by tag and then run a select by class on the results.

Comment: “but the problem is we have duplicate IDs…” you should definitely fix that no matter what. It’s invalid HTML and will perpetually cause you issues.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewMarshall, Yes I agree..  It is a huge list and if I change to class it works but the process is too slow and the browser seams to be hanged...  As you said I may have to change the filtering using webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi All thanks for all your help..

Finally I fixed the issue in following way hope this will help some one..

```
  $.each(propertiesList, function () {
    var item = $('[id="'+ this.id+'"]').parent();
    if(this.property.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
              item.addClass('no-match');
    }
    else {
            item.parents('.root-property-category').show().addClass('expanded').children('ul').show();
             item.removeClass('no-match');
    }
  });
```

This  `$('[id="'+ this.id+'"]')` selects all the elements having id's and it is working fast..

Answer (score 2):

Use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) instead of [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) you can improve the performance a lot

```
var item = $("#available-properties ." + this.id).parent();
```

Comment: `$("#available-properties ." + this.id)` (dot is required)

Comment: @mishik a typo added `'` instead of `.`

Comment: That's what I guessed, but it would not allow me to suggest one-symbol edit.

Comment: This does not work.. it hanged the browser itself... Please provide any other solution...

Comment: Hi I have solved the issue and answered to my own question.. thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var item = $("#available-properties").find("." + this.id).parent();
```

Translated to human it would be: Find element with id available-properties, then find children with class this.id, then find the childs parent.

while

```
$("#available-properties [class*='" + this.id + "']")
```

Says: Find elemens with atribute class this.id, find witch of those are children of element with id available-properties. Much less efficient.

Comment: Hi I have solved the issue and answered to my own question.. thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1):

The issue is how your are looking up by class. You are using : `[class*='" + this.id + "']"`, which is going to find all elements with an attribute `class` equal to `this.id`. I think it will be faster to use `'.' + this.id`, since that is the proper way to look up an element by class. This should be much faster than looking up elements by attribute.

```
var item = $("#available-properties ." + this.id).parent();
```

As an aside, if you are looking for speed increases, replace your `each` function with a `for` loop. This tends to be much faster.

Comment: Hi I have solved the issue and answered to my own question.. thanks for your help..